# Integrating credit card processor with web based Point of Sale on Android Tablet

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, integration, payment-processing, point-of-sale

I'm planning on developing a Web Based Point of Sale that I want to run on Android Tablets, however I'm not sure on how to deal with payment processing. Are there card readers that integrate with Android tablets and the web based POS software running on them? I'm planning on developing the POS using RoR and I'm not sure how will my web application integrate with the card reader? Moreover, I think there will be PCI compliance issues when it comes to Android tablets.

Assuming if I do not use Android Tablets and use a Touchscreen POS Monitor with an embedded card reader would it be possible for the client to swipe their cards which will get the web application to automatically fill out the form fields required for payment processing, which will expedite the checkout process, where eventually the customer will have to enter their CVV2 information and proceed with processing their payments. (Online payment gateway integrated in this scenario).

Kind of lost and want someone to help me make music out of noise please.

Thank you in advance for your assistance in this regards.

Comment: Also is there a possibility where we might attach a card reader with our terminal which will read the customer's card and fill in the order form using data from the card?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm faced with the same problem.